# Data Class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I need to display image by use Data class

I confused in data class I deal with image as image or Int
data class User(val pic : Image)

or
data class User(val pic : Int)

and display it throw CustomAdapter

```
  class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>) :      RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {   
  class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):    CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)

     fun bindItems(user: User) {

  val imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_item) as ImageView

        imageView.setImageResource(pic: )


    }

}
```

I know my code not complete
so I need just example to demonstrate images in Data Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Class should have generic type data, but in your code you are trying to save ImageView.
Below is the sample data class:

```
 data class User(val name: String, val pic: Int)
```

And also adding adapter code below:

```
class HelpAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<HelpAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount() = 10

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

val view =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_navigation_menu,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //here add data to the views
    //If your have list of user data, then you can each user like 
    val user = usersData[position]
    holder.nameTV.text = user.name
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(user.pic)
}

 inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val nameTV = view.tv_name
    val imageView = view.iv_pic
 }
}
```

Comment: I need to display image..from R.drawable.mypic...as example..                 val imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_item) as ImageView        imageView.setImageResource(pic: id )...your code not refer to any image

Comment: you have only one image? or more than one..? If you have more than one image, then you need to save it into data class first as an integer.

Comment: thanks..@Saritha G...your replay help me to solve the problem